Seeking Integration Advice: Utilizing GetX for State Management Alongside GoRouter for Navigation and URL Management
I currently use GetX for state management in my application, but I also want to incorporate GoRouter for navigation and URL management. However, I haven't been able to find any resources on how to combine these two packages. Does anyone have any ideas on how to implement such integration? Currently, I'm using Fluro for navigation, but I'm experiencing issues with navigation history management. On the other hand, GoRouter seems to handle this aspect very well. I'm really struggling and would greatly appreciate your help.
GoRoute(
  path: "/:id",
  pageBuilder: (context, state) {
    var id = state.pathParameters["id"];
    return GetPage(
      name: "/$id",
      page: () => GlobalView(id: id.toString().toLowerCase()),
    );
  },
  routes: [
    GoRoute(
      path: "id", // Nested route for handling product ID
      pageBuilder: (context, state) {
        String id = state.pathParameters["id"] ?? "";
        return GetPage(
          name: "/products/$id",
          page: () => GlobalView(
            id: id,
            anotherChild: const ProductsDetailsView(
              productId: "234567",
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
    ),
  ],
),

Main page
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await setupLocator();
  // // Initialize RemoteService and put it using Get.put
  await Get.putAsync<RemoteService>(() async => await RemoteService().init());

  runApp(const MainApp());
}

// late UserDataController data;

class MainApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MainApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ResponsiveApp(
      builder: (_) => GetBuilder(
        init: Themes(),
        builder: (theme) {
          return AnimatedBuilder(
            key: UniqueKey(),
            animation: theme.animationController,
            builder: (context, child) {
              return GetMaterialApp.router(
                theme: theme.themeData,
                debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
                routeInformationParser: router.routeInformationParser,
                routerDelegate: router.routerDelegate,
                routeInformationProvider: router.routeInformationProvider,
           
                localizationsDelegates: AppLocalizations.localizationsDelegates,
                // locale: AppLocalizations.supportedLocales.elementAt(0),
                locale: const Locale("en"),
                supportedLocales: AppLocalizations.supportedLocales,

                onReady: () async {
                  // Initialize RemoteService and put it using Get.put
                  UserDataController data = Get.put(UserDataController());
                  await data.timeAgoIniter();
                },
              );
            },
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}

